# onPreferenceClick() isn't called from Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm working with Preferences and faced with such trouble: I can't catch why method `onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)` isn't called while I tap on the preference button alike `onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)` is while I change settings.
In the class `SettingsActivity` it works fine (also I have a question: why `else` statement is never true?) but I need it to notify changes and recreate my Activity.

Class `SettingsActivity`:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        mSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Launcher", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Preference clear = findPreference("clear_fav");
        clear.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                String key = preference.getKey();
                if (key.equals("clear_fav")) {
                    Log.d("tag", "LOL");
                    editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("clearFavourite", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Log.d("tag", "NO LOL");
                    editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("clearFavourite", false);
                    editor.apply();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
@Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        int portrait = 0;
        int landscape = 0;
        editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

        if (sharedPreferences.getString("icons_amount", "").equals("1")) {
            portrait = 4;
            landscape = 6;
        } else if (sharedPreferences.getString("icons_amount", "").equals("2")) {
            portrait = 5;
            landscape = 7;
        }

        if (sharedPreferences.getString("themes", "").equals("1")) {
            editor.putBoolean("theme", true);
        } else if (sharedPreferences.getString("themes", "").equals("2")) {
            editor.putBoolean("theme", false);
        }
        editor.putInt("portrait", portrait);
        editor.putInt("landscape", landscape);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

In Class `MyActivity`:

```
@Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Log.d("tag", "RECREATE from Pref Changed");
        recreate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        Log.d("tag", "RECREATE from Click");
        recreate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

`preferences.xml`:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="default_hide"
        android:key="hide_fav"
        android:title="Hide Favourites" />

    <Preference
        android:defaultValue="default_clear_fav"
        android:key="clear_fav"
        android:title="Clear Favourites" />

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="default_icons"
        android:entries="@array/tableListArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/tableListValues"
        android:key="icons_amount"
        android:title="Table" />

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="default_theme"
        android:entries="@array/themeListArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/themeListValues"
        android:key="themes"
        android:title="Theme" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="uri_amount"
        android:title="Uri"/>

    <Preference
        android:defaultValue="default_clear_uri"
        android:key="clear_uri"
        android:title="Clear Uri" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: why you are returning true and false in `OnPreferenceClick` ? Just return true instead of false and delete the return true from if statement....

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't work.